# Split data in non UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have data in **one variable** in the following format -

> dput(head(sol$field))

```
c("À09.05.042 Èññëåäîâàíèå óðîâíÿ àëàíèí-òðàíñàìèíàçû â êðîâè                       0,5 1\r", 
"À09.19.009 Èññëåäîâàíèå êàëà íà ïðîñòåéøèå è ÿéöà ãåëüìèíòîâ                     1   1\r", 
"À26.01.017 Ìèêðîñêîïè÷åñêîå èññëåäîâàíèå îòïå÷àòêîâ ñ ïîâåðõíîñòè êîæè           0,3 1\r", 
"À26.06.073 Îïðåäåëåíèå àíòèòåë ê ñàëüìîíåëëå êèøå÷íîé (Salmonella enterica) â    0,1 1\r", 
"À26.06.074 Îïðåäåëåíèå àíòèòåë ê ñàëüìîíåëëå ïàðàòèôà A (Salmonella paratyphy    0,1 1\r", 
"À26.06.075 Îïðåäåëåíèå àíòèòåë ê ñàëüìîíåëëå ïàðàòèôà Â (Salmonella paratyphy    0,1 1\r"
)
```

I want to split it in 4 columns. See the desired output below -

```
X1              X2                                           X3 X4
À09.05.042  Èññëåäîâàíèå óðîâíÿ àëàíèí-òðàíñàìèíàçû â êðîâè 0,5 1
À09.19.009  Èññëåäîâàíèå êàëà íà ïðîñòåéøèå è ÿéöà ãåëüìèíòîâ   1   1
À26.01.017  Ìèêðîñêîïè÷åñêîå èññëåäîâàíèå îòïå÷àòêîâ ñ ïîâåðõíîñòè êîæè 0,3 1
À26.06.073  Îïðåäåëåíèå àíòèòåë ê ñàëüìîíåëëå êèøå÷íîé (Salmonella enterica) â  0,1 1
À26.06.074  Îïðåäåëåíèå àíòèòåë ê ñàëüìîíåëëå ïàðàòèôà A (Salmonella paratyphy  0,1 1
À26.06.075  Îïðåäåëåíèå àíòèòåë ê ñàëüìîíåëëå ïàðàòèôà Â (Salmonella paratyphy  0,1 1
```

My original data is in UTF-8 form. When I split data using str_split_fixed() function of stringr package, it encodes to "Unknown" form.

There are some cases that do not follow the above pattern exactly.

```
structure(list(field = c("A26.19.002 Áàêòåðèîëîãè÷åñêîå èññëåäîâàíèå        1\r", 
" Â01.001.001        Ïðèåì (îñìîòð, êîíñóëüòàöèÿ) âðà÷à-àêóøåðà-ãèíåêîëîãà     0,5                  1\r", 
" Â01.014.001      Ïðèåì (îñìîòð, êîíñóëüòàöèÿ) âðà÷à-èíôåêöèîíèñòà ïåðâè÷íûé      0,1                   1\r", 
" Â01.026.001      Ïðèåì (îñìîòð, êîíñóëüòàöèÿ) âðà÷à îáùåé ïðàêòèêè (ñåìåéíîãî    0,1                   1\r", 
"Êîä ïî ÌÊÁ X*(1)             À39.1+ Ñèíäðîì Óîòåðõàóñà-Ôðèäåðèêñåíà (Å35.1)\r"
)), .Names = "field", row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Try something like [`(.*?\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s+(.*?)\s{2,}(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s+(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/YFrgAM/1) with `extract`.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `dput(head(sol$field))`?

Comment: Pasted the output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are all of the vectors marked that way or just the simples ones (the one with digits or digits + commas)? If the latter, that shldn't be an issue unless I'm missing something.

```
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)

vec <-c("À09.05.042 Èññëåäîâàíèå óðîâíÿ àëàíèí-òðàíñàìèíàçû â êðîâè                       0,5 1\r", 
"À09.19.009 Èññëåäîâàíèå êàëà íà ïðîñòåéøèå è ÿéöà ãåëüìèíòîâ                     1   1\r", 
"À26.01.017 Ìèêðîñêîïè÷åñêîå èññëåäîâàíèå îòïå÷àòêîâ ñ ïîâåðõíîñòè êîæè           0,3 1\r", 
"À26.06.073 Îïðåäåëåíèå àíòèòåë ê ñàëüìîíåëëå êèøå÷íîé (Salmonella enterica) â    0,1 1\r", 
"À26.06.074 Îïðåäåëåíèå àíòèòåë ê ñàëüìîíåëëå ïàðàòèôà A (Salmonella paratyphy    0,1 1\r", 
"À26.06.075 Îïðåäåëåíèå àíòèòåë ê ñàëüìîíåëëå ïàðàòèôà Â (Salmonella paratyphy    0,1 1\r"
)

Encoding(vec)
## [1] "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8"

vec %>% 
  stri_match_first_regex("^[[:space:]]*([[:alnum:]\\.]+)[[:space:]]+([[:alpha:][:space:][:punct:][:print:]]+)[[:space:]]+([[:digit:],]+)[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]]+)\r", simplify=TRUE) %>% 
  as_data_frame() %>% 
  select(-1) %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(stri_trim_both)) %>% 
  set_names(c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4")) -> xdf

xdf
## # A tibble: 6 x 4
##           X1                                                                 X2    X3    X4
##        <chr>                                                              <chr> <chr> <chr>
## 1 À09.05.042                    Èññëåäîâàíèå óðîâíÿ àëàíèí-òðàíñàìèíàçû â êðîâè   0,5     1
## 2 À09.19.009                  Èññëåäîâàíèå êàëà íà ïðîñòåéøèå è ÿéöà ãåëüìèíòîâ     1     1
## 3 À26.01.017        Ìèêðîñêîïè÷åñêîå èññëåäîâàíèå îòïå÷àòêîâ ñ ïîâåðõíîñòè êîæè   0,3     1
## 4 À26.06.073 Îïðåäåëåíèå àíòèòåë ê ñàëüìîíåëëå êèøå÷íîé (Salmonella enterica) â   0,1     1
## 5 À26.06.074 Îïðåäåëåíèå àíòèòåë ê ñàëüìîíåëëå ïàðàòèôà A (Salmonella paratyphy   0,1     1
## 6 À26.06.075 Îïðåäåëåíèå àíòèòåë ê ñàëüìîíåëëå ïàðàòèôà Â (Salmonella paratyphy   0,1     1

walk(xdf, ~print(Encoding(.x)))
## [1] "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8"
## [1] "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8"
## [1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
## [1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"

Encoding(as.character(0:9))
## [1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It runs well for 95% cases. For some of the records, it returns missing as last column might be missing OR it has digit+comma. See the structure of these cases -

c("A26.19.002 Áàêòåðèîëîãè÷åñêîå èññëåäîâàíèå        1\r", "À09.05.199     Èññëåäîâàíèå óðîâíÿ îïóõîëåàññîöèèðîâàííûõ àíòèãåíîâ â             0,6                0,75\r", 
"À09.05.202     Èññëåäîâàíèå óðîâíÿ àíòèãåíà àäåíîãåííûõ ðàêîâ Ñà 125 â êðîâè      0,4                0,75\r", 
"À12.06.011     Ïðîâåäåíèå ðåàêöèè Âàññåðìàíà (RW)                                 1                  6,5\r"
)

Comment: If you could add the errant cases to the original Q that'd be 

Comment: Sure. I am unable to do it via mobile as formating goes haywire. I'll do it tomorrow. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I have added these cases. Please help!

Comment: Well, two of those lines are not in the format you want (i.e. they don't have the fields you say you want/need). I've updated the answer with a regex (it was one, small change to the regex and you would do well to try to tweak those on your own as it's hard to learn how to except with experience which is usually trial & error with regexes). But for the two that don't meet the format criteria, you have not indicated what you want to do with those. However, your question was about encodings, not regex parsing, and scope creep is frowned upon in SO land.